# Having trouble updating React child component when passed prop from parent is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, sockets

In my backend, I have a socket.io, Node, Express setup that I have tested works properly, and is emitting the right number of broadcasts to the right client. `socket.emit("team_set", gameInfo);`

Now in the client, I have `App.js` which listens for this and sets a couple of states.
These states are being passed down to child components (multiple layers down as well), and the components SHOULD be receiving new CSS "styles" to show but it isn't updating. I'm not sure what the issue is.

App.js

```
const [teamStyle, setTeamStyle] = useState({}); // a CSS style
const [seats, setSeats] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("team_set", (gameInfo) => {
      setTeamStyle(gameInfo.teamStyle);
      setSeats(gameInfo.seats);
      setGameStarted(true);
      console.log("team set called: ", gameInfo.teamStyle, gameInfo.seats);
    });

    return () => {
      socket.off('team_set'); 
    };
  }, []);
  ...

  return (
    <GameScreen
        socket={socket}
        username={username}
        seats={seats}
        teamStyle={teamStyle}
        numPlayers={numPlayers}
        gameStarted={gameStarted}
    />
```

GameScreen.jsx

```
...
return (
    <div className="gameScreen">
      <div>
        <PlayerBox 
          seats={seats}
          teamStyle={teamStyle} 
          numPlayers={numPlayers} 
          gameStarted={gameStarted}
        />
      ...

export default memo(GameScreen);
```

PlayerBox.jsx

```
return (
  <Player teamStyle={teamStyle}/>
```

Player.jsx

```
function Player(teamStyle) {  
  return (
    <div style={teamStyle}>
      <Fist />
    </div>
  )
}

export default memo(Player);
```

The teamStyle should be changing the color of my Player component but it isn't and I'm not sure why...

Comment: `function Player(teamStyle)` In this code, `teamStyle` is the entire props object. Did you mean `function Player({ teamStyle })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// change props. `teamStyle` to `{teamStyle}`
function Player({teamStyle}) {  
  return (
    <div style={teamStyle}>
      <Fist />
    </div>
  )
}

export default memo(Player);
```

Comment: My gooooooodness, thanks -_-